# Java. removeAll() Collections

Tags: java, время

Имеется две коллекции (допустим, два List'а String'ов, но это не столь важно).
Хочется удалить из коллекции A все элементы коллекции B.
Очевидно, это можно сделать A.removeAll(B). 
Проблема - это достаточно долго по времени происходит.

Оттого и вопрос - возможно ли это оптимизировать? Сделать каким-то образом этот процесс быстрее?

Спасибо!

Comment: можно самому написать код, но, наверное, встроенный метод все равно сделает это быстрее

Comment: Порядок элементов в коллекциях сохранять нужно?

Comment: да, хотелось бы сохранить порядок элементов в первой коллекции

Comment: Для коллекции `B` вместо [списка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) используйте [множество](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), это должно ускорить процесс.

Answer (score 2):

```
A.removeAll(new HashSet<>(B))
```

Comment: чем это отличается от A.removeAll(B)?

Comment: Какова асимптотика получается?
В классическом варианте A.removeAll(B) время работы O(n*m), где n, m - размеры коллекций соответственно. Что происходит при аналогичной работе, но уже с map'ами?

Comment: @ctrlaltdel `O(n + m)`

Comment: Интересная фишка, никогда не задумывался.

Comment: Добавьте текстовый комментарий к вашему коду, объясняющий ваш ответ